# Hung creating new Windows Azure storage

Tags: azure, storage

Earlier today I had to delete an existing Windows Azure storage instance (testing several changes from a clean slate).  A few minutes later, and from within the online Azure management portal, I created a new storage instance with the same name.  It's been stuck with a status of "Creating" for several hours.

Is there a way to reset/kick an Azure process which is stuck?

Comment: Related to this. When deleting a storage account and creating a new one with the same name. It can take some minutes before the dns have been updated, meaning you cant connect to the new storage account before the dns is updated. (took like 2-4 minutes for me the other day).